# php loop question

Tags: php, loops

hello i'm beginner for programming I've got a homework. googled it but couldnt find anything...

i need to get the total value of numbers from 1 to 10. this need to be done in loop. but couldn't figure which loop should i use. if you can also give me an example code thats would be great.

Comment: This won't fulfil your homework assignment, but `array_sum(range(1,10))` would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$start = 0; // set the variable that will hold our total

for($i=1;$i<11;$i++){ // set a loop, read here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php for more info
  $start += $i; // add $i to our start value
}
echo $start; // display our final value
```

Comment: others also works but this one is well commented so i'll choose this as answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is a homework question, I'm not sure why people are just giving you an answer to copy-paste.

Achieving the sum of numbers `1..10` is pretty simple. You will need to initialise an empty int var before your loop, and for each iteration from `0` up to *and including* `10` you will add your int var to the current iteration.

For example:

```
sum = 0;

for num in range 1 to 10:
    sum = sum + num;
```

Comment: agreed, some people are *to* helpful

Comment: that's not an example its an answer.

Comment: @Prisoner: Figuring out an answer for yourself proves much more fruitful and rewarding.

Comment: It looks like you just re-wrote the question with pseudo-code. How is this an answer to the question about `php` and loops?

Comment: @Russel, I do agree but when you have no idea where to start seeing some examples and links to relevant information is much more helpful than sitting there hacking it to work over the space of an hour (in my opinion).

Comment: @Dragon, it was an example of what he was looking for. There were many ways to achieve what he wanted and I provided an example of one of them.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @Russell, according to those guidelines if the student hasn't appeared to try and answer the question then the question should be down-voted and closed. Where was your downvote?

Comment: @Prisoner: I have only down voted once since the conception of this account, and that was truly deserving. This is not worth breaking out of my cycle.

Comment: @Rusell, Learning through examples helped me mostly when I first started programming therefore I gave an example that would have helped me. Shall we just agree to disagree?

Comment: @Prisoner: I'm not sure why you keep choosing to pursue this. I disagreed a long time ago and left it at that. You're the one that keeps asking the questions. I'm glad you learnt from examples, I just hope that there will never be a shortage of examples :P

Comment: @Rusell Why I keep choosing to pursue this? I'm simply replying to each of your comments, problem?

Comment: @Prisoner: All my answers were in statements; replying to your questions.

Comment: @Rusell, statements that require clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `for` loop.

```
$total = 0;

for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
  $total += $i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using the for loop:**

```
<?php

$sum = 0;

for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
  $sum += $i;
}
```

**Using the foreach loop:**

```
<?php

$sum = 0;

foreach(range(1,10) as $num){

  $sum += $num;

}

echo $sum; // prints 55
```

And disregarding your assignment, here is an easier way:

```
echo array_sum(range(1,10));
```